# Dynamically Generated Razor Sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I have a three tiered layout structure in my ASP.Net MVC 4 site.  My pages reference a layout and that layout uses a superlayout.  In my superlayout I have this code...

```
@{
    tabCount = 0;
    foreach (string tabName in @ViewBag.LayoutConfiguration.LowerTabbing.Tabs) {
        tabCount++;
        var tabId = string.Format("BodyOfTab{0}", tabCount);
        <div id="@tabId">
            @RenderSection(tabId, false)   
        </div>
    }
}
```

In my pages I explicitly define a number of sections like this...

```
@section BodyOfTab1{
    <div id="detailBody1" />
}
@section BodyOfTab2{
    <div id="detailBody2" />
}
@section BodyOfTab3{
    <div id="detailBody3" />
}
```

However my middle layout is preventing all of this from working becuase I can't seem to autogenerate the required "forwarding" sections from `@ViewBag.LayoutConfiguration.LowerTabbing.Tabs`.  Ideally I'd like to autogenerate the following in my middle layout, but the number of sections is not known at compile time...

```
@section BodyOfTab1{
    @RenderSection("BodyOfTab1")
}
@section BodyOfTab2{
    @RenderSection("BodyOfTab2")
}
@section BodyOfTab3{
    @RenderSection("BodyOfTab3")
}
```

Is this in any way possible?

**Update:**
I've tried this, but it doesn't work for some reason I don't quite understand right now...

```
@{
    DefineSection("BodyOfTab1", () =>
    {
        RenderSection("BodyOfTab1");
    });
    DefineSection("BodyOfTab2", () =>
    {
        RenderSection("BodyOfTab2");
    });
    DefineSection("BodyOfTab3", () =>
    {
        RenderSection("BodyOfTab3");
    });
}
```

Comment: can you use a partialView for it?